# C# BinaryTree implementation

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree, sortedset, sorteddictionary

I need a binary tree or another structure in which I can store objects with a time stamp and then QUICKLY look them up not just by the timestamp I know is there but also by a range

```
    (timestamp > min && timestamp < max).
```

I found SortedDictionary and SortedSet that both implement a binary tree. What I am missing is the ability to look up by range > && < without forcing it (SortedDictionary or SortedSet) internally to iterate over more elements than they need to.

What I mean is when I call

```
 SortedDictionary.TryGetValue(DateTime.Now, ...
```

it should take logarithmic time.

I want to be able to get all items between Min and Max in logarithmic time as well. Missing

```
SortedDictionary.TryGetValueBetween(DateTime.Now-SomeInterval, DateTime.Now+SomeInterval,...
```

If I was implementing the binary tree myself it would not be a problem. But I do not see a mechanism for doing it with SortedDictionary or SortedSet. And I don't want to resort to linear time.

Am I just not finding the right methods or do I really need to implement the binary tree myself to get the benefits I am looking for?

Other options are also welcome. Is there a different structure that would give me insert, delete and "range lookup" in log time or better.

Comment: You won't be able to use either of those BCL types.  You'll need to use your own or a third party tree structure.

Comment: When you can tolerate linear time for insert (& delete) you can use a simple array. The good old [BinarySearch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  method will give you the closest (lower) index.

Comment: Thanks Henk, but no I do need all 3 in log(n) as I mentioned in the question. Found some solutions though. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found 2 solutions:

1. On closer inspection SortedSet does have the method I need: [GetViewBetween](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. In a free third party library called Wintellect.PowerCollections there is OrderedMultiDictionary class (see [here](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/PowerCollections/OrderedMultiDictionary.cs)) that does what I need plus allows duplicates into the collection (unlike SortedSet). The method for getting a range between 2 values is called Range().

Both as far as I can tell do inserts, deletes and lookups in log(n) time.